# Limited xAxis between min and max datetime in HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I use Spline HighChart With This Style.

My Data For Example Is Between 2013 AND 2015 And XAxis Of Chart Is Between This DateTime, But I Want To Be Between  2014 AND 2015.

I Want The XAis Exactly Between t1 AND t2 AND I don't Want To Show Data Out Of This Range

```
function liveLineChart(container, series, loadFunction, StartDate) {
var chart;
$('#' + container).highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        resetZoomButton: {
            position: {
                x: 0,
                y: -30
            }
        },
        type: 'spline',
        animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
        marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {
                loadFunction(this.series);
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Alarms '
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickPixelInterval: 150,
        //min: StartDate
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Value'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }],
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            turboThreshold: 0
        },
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        //enabled: false,
        formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y/%m/%d<br/>%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                   Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
        },
        style: {
            fontSize: '8.5px'
        }
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: true
    },
    series: series
});
}
```

I want To this Xaxis of Live Chart be limited with specific min And Max DateTime.

But This Char couldn't Work properly

Comment: It looks right, except your xAxis.min and xAxis.max is not defined. Heres an example where I am defining a min and max: http://jsfiddle.net/TheIronDeveloper/p8xLn5jj/

Comment: Note, I am defining the min/max by a Date.UTC value.

Comment: Apart of min/max values you should set startOnTick parameter, adapt tickInterval or simpler, use tickPositioner. All of parameters are in our [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)